# Doing c# class library a runnable application

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a console applicaiton and add it to another class library projects. So my class libraries will be runnable applicaitons.

[image]

```
namespace MyWorker.Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }

    public interface IConfiguration
    {
        void Configure();
    }
}
```

And I am adding my `MyWorker.Host` as reference to `MyWorker.Client` class library project. And debug settings set as "Start external program".

[image]

And now I want to search client assemblies that referenced **MyWorker.Host**. I will find classes that implemented `IConfiguration` interface.

```
namespace MyWorker.Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var implementations = AppDomain
                .CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(assemly => assemly.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => !t.IsInterface)
                .Where(t => typeof (IConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(t));

            foreach (var assembly in implementations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

But console writes **nothing**.

(If I add a concrate class in MyWorker.Host it writes console.)

Comment: You can't run a class library. They're to be consumed by other (runnable) applications only

Comment: Did you intend to Add a Reference to your Console Application ? `References > Right Click > Add References > Projects > Solution` and choose the `class Library`.  A Class Library has no entry point and can't be "Runnable"

Comment: Well, of course it writes nothing. The assembly `MyWorker.Client` isn't loaded in the application domain - you need to load it first. The executable that runs is still just `MyWorker.Host` with no magic to load the DLL for you - you need to setup build dependencies, copy the DLLs, and explicitly load them as needed.

Comment: MyWorker.Client isn't loaded in the application domain. How can I load assemblies in Environment.CurrentDirectory?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing before but had to look through DLLs for classes that implement the interface you're after using Reflection.  Of course you need a means of passing in that path, which could be configurable, or just look through all subdirectories from the solution directory, etc.